# Broken front derailleur 7400 Dura Ace

Tags: shimano, derailleur, derailleur-front

The chain came off a couple of times while I was riding yesterday and when I tried to put the chain back, the small screw came off from front derailleur.

I think maybe that’s a thing to attach the plate and where it moves.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhxz1.jpg]
  [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P846.jpg]

Comment: I do not even now what these parts are, but the small one clearly appears to connect the two pieces and is inserted from the back one and screwed into the front one.

Comment: Can you please add a wider angle photo showing where this detail is on the derailleur

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I’ve just added two photos.

Answer (score 2):

You should connect the holes visible in fig. 2 using the screw in fig. 1. It is not very well visible, but the small piece should accept an Allen key and it is screwed from the rear side (see first picture below). It should ultimately be screwed into the bigger piece marked in the other picture below.

[image]

I marked the relevant place on a photograph from pedalpedlar.co.uk. I hope this counts as fair use.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I’ve been trying to do it but it’s extremely hard to screw into the piece you mentioned. I’ll do my best to fix it thank you anyways.

Comment: @Eddy The threads may be damaged and may require someone with the skills and tools for thread tapping. If that can help at all, I have zero experience in that.

Comment: I can see through all holes there but it doesn’t fit. I’ll keep trying to fix it but if I can’t I would replace it.